# how to hide image in asp.net without behidcode

Tags: asp.net, .net

i want to hide the image symbol if there is no image of that item.

suppose if i have an item pencil but it doesn't have image then it will not show there..

But in my case there is no image of pencil but it will show broken image symbol

i don't want that..

```
     <div class="image-item">
       <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageData")%>' CssClass="image-show" >
 </div>
```

this is my code...and it is in repeater ..

Comment: Use JavaScript to hide it. Although it may be better to have a placeholder image saying "this item doesn't have an image". That would allow you to keep your layout consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="image-item">
       <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageData")%>' CssClass="image-show" Visible='<%#!DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageData")=="null")%>' >
 </div>
```

Best of Luck

Comment: Why `ToString`? Just do `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Image") == null`

Comment: @Andrei..i thought it may be contain path of image..thats why i wrote Tostring()

Comment: @jayrathod...see my updated answer...and let me know.